# Generic return type of function in Typescript

Tags: function, generics, typescript

I'm new to ts but I've learnt a little about the concept of generics in java. The query is that I have three functions : searchTrack, searchAlbum, searchArtist

```
  searchTrack(query: string): Observable<Track[]> {
    return this.search(query, 'track');
  }

  searchArtist(query: string): Observable<Artist[]> {
    return this.search(query, 'artist');
  }

  searchAlbum(query: string): Observable<Album[]> {
    return this.search(query, 'album');
  }
```

I want a general function 'search' in this class that takes the query and the type of entity and returns an Observable of collection of a specific entity type. I'm stuck here. How can I work with generics to specify a generic return type of a function.

```
search(query: string, type: string): Observable<Array<T>> {
 return this.query(`/search`, [
   `q=${query}`,
   `type=${type}`
 ]);
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using the **Array** class instead of [].
Also define a generic T type on the search function.

```js
search<T>(query: string, type: string): Observable<Array<T>> {
 return this.query(`/search`, [
   `q=${query}`,
   `type=${type}`
 ]);
}
```

You should be able to call it like this:

```js
let result = search<Artist>('someQuery', 'artist');
```

You can find more about generics in typescript in the Generics chapter in the handbook [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Answer (score 2):

As @toskv answered, you can add a generics type to the method signature, but the compiler has no way of inferring the type so you'll have to add it:

```
myObj.search<Track>(query, "track");
```

However, you can do something like:

```
interface MyObservableClass {}

interface MyObservableClassCtor<T extends MyObservableClass> {
    new (): T;
    getType(): string;
}

class Artist implements MyObservableClass {
    static getType(): string {
        return "artist";
    }
}

class Album implements MyObservableClass {
    static getType(): string {
        return "album";
    }
}

class Track implements MyObservableClass {
    static getType(): string {
        return "track";
    }
}

class Searcher {
    search<T extends MyObservableClass>(ctor: MyObservableClassCtor<T>, query: string): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.query(`/search`, [
            `q=${query}`,
            `type=${ ctor.getType() }`
        ]);
    }
}

let searcher: Searcher = ...;

searcher.search(Track, "...");
```

And then the compiler can infer what the `T` is by providing it with the class (/ctor).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with overloads:

```
class A {
    search<T>(query: string, type: "Track"): Observable<Track[]>;
    search<T>(query: string, type: "Artist"): Observable<Artist[]>;
    search<T>(query: string, type: "Album"): Observable<Album[]>;
    search<T>(query: string, type: string): Observable<T[]>;
    search<T>(query: string, type: string): Observable<T[]> {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which will give you the correct type:

```
var observable = x.search("test", "Track");
```

And this will give a compile error on incompatible objects:

```
var observableError: Observable<Album[]> = x.search("test", "Track");
```